# ng build angular 2 project with proxy configuration replaced

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment, build

Based on suggestion in http://www.meekdeveloper.com/angular-cli-asp-net-core-windows-authentication/, I have used proxy config to call ASP.NET Web API from Angular 2

```
ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.js
```

proxy config is as follow:

```
    const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

module.exports = {  
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost/ApplicationApi/',
            secure: false,
            agent: new Agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000
            }),
            onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                let key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
                    proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            }
        }
};
```

It is working for development fine but there is no proxy config parameter for `ng-build`.

I want to deploy the app into IIS, how can keep URL prefix (http://localhost/ApplicationApi/) without changing the source code?